# DataFrame Logic To Remove Rows Not Working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

**Background** - I have a pandas DataFrame, which I have performed some math on, in order to calculate values to populate the `Entity ID` and `% Ownership` column with -

`df['Entity ID %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)`
`df['Account # %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)`

I then resave the DataFrame with only rows for those 2x columns whos value `!=1` or `!=0`, as specified by this messy line of code. This forms my 'Exception Report' -

`df = df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Entity ID %'] != 0.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 0.0000000)]`

I then request that both column's values are rounded to 7-decimal places -
`df = df.round({'Entity ID %': 7, 'Account # %': 7})`

Finally, the DataFrame is written to a `.xlsx` file -

```
with open(filename, 'w') as output_data:
        df.to_excel(filename+'.xlsx', sheet_name='Ownership Exception Report')
```

**Issue** - despite the code to resave the DataFrame with only rows that are `!= 1` or `!=0`, some rows that have `1` values in both columns still remain and are written to the `xlsx`, despite meeting the criteria to be removed.

**Function 1** - this creates the `Entity ID %` and `Account # %` columns, as well as performing math, that will populate those columns -

```
def ownership_qc():
    df = unpack_response()
    df['Entity ID %'] = '-'
    df['Account # %'] = '-'
    df['Reason to Dismiss'] = '-'
    df['Entity ID %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)
    df['Account # %'] = df.groupby('Entity ID')['% Ownership'].transform(sum)
    return df
```

**Function 2** - this resaves the DataFrame with the criteria mentioned above (`!=0` or `!=1`) before rounding to 7-decimal places, and finally writing to the `.csv`.

```
def ownership_exceptions():
    df = ownership_qc()
    df = df[(df['Entity ID %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Entity ID %'] != 0.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 1.0000000) & (df['Account # %'] != 0.0000000)]
    df = df.round({'Entity ID %': 7, 'Account # %': 7})
    #   Counting rows in df
    index = df.index
    number_of_rows = len(index)
    timestr = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
    filename = 'ownership_exceptions_'+timestr
    with open(filename, 'w') as output_data:
        df.to_excel(filename+'.xlsx', sheet_name='Ownership Exception Report')
    print("---------------------------\n","EXCEPTION REPORT:", number_of_rows, "rows", "\n---------------------------")
    return df
```

Is anyone able to help me identify why some rows that meet the criteria to be removed, still remain in my DataFrame and thus still being written to the `.xlsx` file?

I am hoping my logic is flawed and it's an easy fix, however I have reached a dead-end troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a close look at your code, I can see that you are initializing

```
 df['Entity ID %'] = '-'
 df['Account # %'] = '-'
```

which makes them datatype **object**. You can not compare object with integers.

Make the following change in your ownership_qc():

```
 df['Entity ID %'] = 0
 df['Account # %'] = 0
```

That will help!

Comment: Thanks Ammar - I have made that change, for best practices. However, it doesn't explain why some rows (that meet the criteria to be dropped) still remain.

Comment: Hi @William, it does explain. When you initialize it with "-", it becomes object datatype. In this case it will not recognize 0 or 1 because they are integers. You will have to put 0 and 1 inside inverted commas like this: "0" or "1".

Comment: I apologize - this now makes sense and I accepted your answer. Thank you for your support!